# Having trouble building a math Calculator

Tags: java

I am trying to build a math Calculator in Java but I am having problems with it, I want to build it with methods and not just int.

I am having problems with how to print the return value (rishon+sheni) and also how to check if the `in.nextLine()` that the console wrote equal to plus like that:

```
    package mehadash;
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class lilmod {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        String plus = null;
        String minus = null;
        String math;
        int sum = 0;

        System.out.println("What kind of math you want to do?");
        math = in.nextLine();
        if(math = plus)
        {
            System.out.println("Enter the two numbers you would like to check");
            SumNumbers(in.nextInt(),in.nextInt());

            System.out.println("The answer is :" +SumNumbers());
        }



    minusNumbers(in.nextInt(),in.nextInt());
    }
    public static int SumNumbers(int rishon , int sheni)
    {
        return rishon + sheni;

    }
    public static int minusNumbers(int rishon , int sheni)
    {
        return rishon - sheni;
    }

}
```

Comment: `if(math = plus)` should be `if(math == plus)` but if you are comparing strings (which you are doing here) you must use `equals` and not `==`, `if(math.equals(plus))`. But your `plus` is `null`

Answer (score 0):

You can always just define more variables.

```
int numberA = in.nextInt();
int numberB = in.nextInt();


int result = SumNumbers(numberA, numberB);


System.out.println("The result: " + result);
```

Answer (score 0):

> how to print the return value (rishon+sheni)

Try this way:

`System.out.println("The answer is :" +SumNumbers(in.nextInt(),in.nextInt()));`

instead of

```
SumNumbers(in.nextInt(),in.nextInt()); 
System.out.println("The answer is :" +SumNumbers());
```

> also how to check if the in.nextLine(); that the console wrote equal
>   to plus

Try

```
if(math.equals("+"))
```

instead of

```
if(math = plus)
```